# Error al desplegar App Web en Glassfish 5.0.1 mediante war

Tags: java, jsf, centos, glassfish

Tratando de modernizar un servidor de mi empresa, estamos instalando versiones modernas de tecnologias que el anterior utilizaba. El dilema actual esta en conseguir desplegar en Gassfish 5.0.1 varias apps Web que estaban desplegadas en Glassfish 3.0.2 .

Sistema:

- CentOS 8
- Varios JDK's instalados con alternatives:

  - JDK 1.7_80
  - JDK 1.8_261
  - openJDK1.8 (default)
- Glassfish 5.0.1

El error mostrado al hacer *sudo asadmin deploy aplicacion.war* es el siguiente:

> remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
> Source Document: jar:file:/opt/sun/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/WebForestAdmin/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-extensions-dynamic-faces-0.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
> Cause: Class 'com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.renderkit.ScriptsRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/shale/remoting/XhtmlHelper;. Please see server.log for more details.
> Command deploy failed.

En server.log dice practicamente lo mismo pero mas extendido:

```
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
  Source Document: jar:file:/opt/sun/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/WebForestAdmin/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-extensions-dynamic-faces-0.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.renderkit.ScriptsRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/shale/remoting/XhtmlHelper;
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:136)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:408)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:377)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:174)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

Estas aplicaciones son originales de mi empresa creadas para funciones muy concretas que nosotros necesitamos. Fueron escritas hace muchos años, por lo que me resulta muy difícil saber ningún tipo de información técnica al respecto.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar,

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Compilaron esas aplicaciones con ESA librería que te indica, presente como dependencia. Sin embargo, no fue incluida al empaquetar y el servidor tampoco la tiene para incluirla en el classpath. La aplicación la está pidiendo y no la encuentra.

Puedes descargar el JAR [desde Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.faces.extensions/jsf-extensions-dynamic-faces/0.2/jar) e incluirlo en el lib del contexto o del servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He intentado añadirlo al lib del servidor pero sigue dando el mismo error. Despues he investigado el .war de la app y esta ya contiene el jar. aun asi te dice lo mismo: ' Source Document: jar:file: /opt/sun/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/WebForestAdmin/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-extensions-dynamic-faces-0.1.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml

Cause: Class 'com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.renderkit.ScriptsRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/shale/remoting/XhtmlHelper;'